# Debug buttons are disabled in Delphi 2007 IDE. Why?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Debug buttons are disabled in Delphi 2007 IDE. I can build project with command line or Project -> Build, but cannot run application or either attach to process.

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this issue in the past and can help me.

Few facts:

- Delphi 2007 IDE was installed on my machine and worked just fine.
- Debug buttons got disabled at one point of time and I have no idea what was the reason.
- I tried reinstalling Delphi, but this did not help.
- License for Delphi is ok.
- I suppose that there should be
  something with either registry or 3rd
  party components.
- I'm .NET developer and need investigate some piece of Delphi code, so please do not blame me :)

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Ok, so I reinstalled Delphi from scratch on brand new system and everything went fine. In other words it was and it is odd reason why my buttons disappeared. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613499/delphi-compiler-options-for-debugging

Comment: Map file should also be set to "detailed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I figure it out later (from Delphi developers from different team) issue was with 3rd party components to Delphi. They stored something into registry. It was enough to change some registry keys, they did this so I cannot post it here.

Very interesting how it could be that such components got shipped.

Answer (score 2):

Possibility...
Go to pull down menu: 'Project/Options/Compiler' and set in field 'Build Configuration' to 'Debug'. In filed 'Debugging' switch-on first 5 switches like 'Debugging Informations' and so on!

Comment: Map file should also be set to "detailed"

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for this behaviour of debug buttons disabled is that the target executable is not active in the Project Manager pane.
You need to right click the target .exe in the Project Manager pane and choose the "Activate" menu action.
Then, the green run arrow becomes available.
I also noted that not having the target .exe activated also affects the GExperts and the Ctrl-F12 "View Unit" system, which is very handy. i.e. Ctrl-F12 does nothing if the target .exe in the Project Manager pane is not marked active.
(I also wondered if Dell notebook had hijacked Ctrl-F12 .. but think that is a separate subject and solution).
Hope this comment helps !